# Call to template function using string of the type

Tags: c#, templates

I need to call a template function, something like:

```
void myFunc<T>();
```

I have the template type as string and I want to call the function using the type I have as string.
For example if i want to call it for the Exception type, instead of calling:

```
myFunc<Exception>()
```

i need to do it like:

```
string type = "Exception";
myFunc<type>();
```

(i need to parse an object from json string, and i'm getting the type of the object as a string)

Is there a way to do something like this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generic type has to be known at **compile type** in order to call a generic method the classical way.

So without reflection, you need to implicitly specify the type `myFunc<string>()`.

However, using reflection you can specify the type at run-time. Consider the below sample:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string xyz = "abc";

        BindingFlags methodflags = BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public;

        MethodInfo mi = typeof(Program).GetMethod("MyFunc", methodflags);

        mi.MakeGenericMethod(xyz.GetType()).Invoke(null, null);
    }

    public static void MyFunc<T>()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(typeof(T).FullName);
    }
}
```

`MyFunc` prints `System.String`

Comment: Thanks, but i think you didn't understand my question. I edit it to be more clear.

Comment: @amichai Well, you can do that using reflection only. Check my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks, I believe you meant to write Type.GetType(xyz)) instead of xyz.GetType(),

Comment: @amichai both return the same result.

Comment: the xyz.GetType() will return type string, and Type.GetType(xyz)) will return type abc